# How do I numerically integrate a function thats a product of a lorentzian and a cosinus in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I am new to stackoverflow and also quite new to Python. So, I hope to ask my question in an appropriate manner.
I am running a Python code similar to this minimal example with an example function that is a product of a lorentzian with a cosinus that I want to numerically integrate:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad

#minimal example:
omega_loc = 15
gamma = 5

def Lorentzian(w):
    #print(w)
    return (w**3)/((w/omega_loc) + 1)**2*(gamma/2)/((w-omega_loc)**2+(gamma/2)**2)

def intRe(t):
    return quad(lambda w: w**(-2)*Lorentzian(w)*(1-np.cos(w*t)),0,np.inf,limit=10000)[0]


plt.figure(1)
plot_range = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
plt.plot(plot_range, [intRe(t) for t in plot_range])
```

Independent on the upper limit of the integration I never get the code to run and to give me a result.
When I enable the `#print(w)` line it seems like the code just keeps on probing the integral at random different values of w in an infinite loop (?). Also the console gives me a detection of a roundoff error.
Is there a different way for numerical integration in Python that is better suited for this kind of function than the quad function or did I do a more fundamental error?

Comment: If you integrate to `100` instead of `np.inf`, the integration result will be much quicker and it'll not be that far off from the `np.inf` result. Not sure about the reason but it might be the detection of the infinity conversion is not working well for your function. I'll leave this to the experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observations

1. Close to zero `(1 - cos(w*t)) / w**2` tends to `0/0`. We can take the taylor expansion t**2(1/2 - (w*t)**2/24).
2. Going to the infinity the Lorentzian is a constant  and the cosine term will cause the output to oscillate indefinitely, the integral can be approximated by multiplying that term by a slowly decreasing term.
3. You are using a linearly spaced scale with many points. It is easier to visualize with `w` in log scale.

The plot looks like this before damping the cosine term

[image]

I introduced two parameters to tune the attenuation of the oscilations

```py
def cosinus_term(w, t, damping=1e4*omega_loc):
    return np.where(abs(w*t) < 1e-6,  t**2*(0.5 - (w*t)**2/24.0), (1-np.exp(-abs(w/damping))*np.cos(w*t))/w**2)
def intRe(t, damping=1e4*omega_loc):
    return quad(lambda w: cosinus_term(w, t)*Lorentzian(w),0,np.inf,limit=10000)[0]
```

Plotting with the following code

```
plt.figure(1)
plot_range = np.logspace(-3,3,100)
plt.plot(plot_range, [intRe(t, 1e2*omega_loc) for t in plot_range])
plt.plot(plot_range, [intRe(t, 1e3*omega_loc) for t in plot_range])
plt.xscale('log')
```

It runs in less than 3 minutes here, and the two results are close to each other, specially for large `w`, suggesting that the damping doesn't affect too much the result.

[image]

Comment: That helped me alot in terms of how to approach such a function and how one can treat it, thanks!

Comment: Good to know. That is the idea, building skills, not only getting answers :)